# ¿Donde esta ele error en mi bucle python?

Tags: python, bucles

Buenas tengo que hacer un bucle donde se le pregunte a los usuarios su edad, según la edad que se introduzca, tengo que mostrar un mensaje.

```
while True:
    edad = input("que edad tiene? ")
    edad =int(edad)
    if edad < 3:
        print("el niño entra gratis")
    if edad > 3 and edad >= 12:
        print("el precio de la entrada son 8€")
```

Comment: Disculpad, el contenido que hay dentro del bucle esta sangrado

Comment: Lee sobre la Indentación en Python.

Comment: Cual sería el comportamiento esperado? Se me ocurren dos cosas a las que podrías estarte refiriendo como "error": 1- Que el bucle sea infinito 2- Que intentes ingresar algo no numerico y se produsca un error.

Comment: Esto `if edad > 3 and edad >= 12:` se reduce a `if edad >= 12:`

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el segundo if:

`if edad > 3 and edad >= 12: print("el precio de la entrada son 8€")`

Tienes un error con los operadores, `edad > 3` y `edad >= 6`

Seguramente buscas:

`elif edad > 3 and edad <= 12: print("el precio de la entrada son 8€")`

Ahora tienes un problema con los niños de 3 años.

Lo puedes dejar como:

```
while True:
    edad = input("que edad tiene? (-1 para salir): ")
    edad =int(edad)
    if edad < 0: break
    elif edad <= 3: print("el niño entra gratis")
    elif 3 < edad <= 12: print("el precio de la entrada son 8€")
    else: print('Pagas como adulto')
```